# fatal error: editline/readline.h: No such file or directory compilation terminated

Tags: c, editline

Fatal Error

I am working on makeyourownlisp,where in editline/readline.h and
editline/history.h have to be added to the program.
Following is the code snippet

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

#include<editline/readline.h>
#include<editline/history.h>

static char  input[2048];

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    printf("CLISP version 1.02\n");
    printf("Ctrl + c to exit\n");

    while(1)
    {
        char * input = readline(">>> \n");
        add_history(input);

        printf("%s", input);
        free(input);
    }
}
```

I have already installed libedit-20170329-3.1(containing the above mentioned header files) but how to use the files and get the code rolling is something I need help about.

Comment: Where did you install `libedit` to? That is, where are those header files?

Comment: In a folder containing the program's(above code snippet) file. Is it the right place i am working on windows10 environment.

Comment: In that case try: `#include "editline/readline.h"` and 
 `#include "editline/history.h"`. That is, use double quotes instead of angle brackets.

Comment: It did'nt work...

Answer (score 3):

On Debian Buster 10, I had to install the package with:

```
sudo apt install libeditline-dev
```

Instead of:

```
#include <editline/readline.h>
#include <editline/history.h>
```

I just included:

```
#include <editline.h>
```

ran the program with -leditline flag and worked perfectly.
Note that I was executing the portable program for both Windows and UNIX systems. Following the tutorial, that piece of my code would look like:

```
// otherwise include the editline headers
#else
#include <editline.h>
#endif
```

Hope that helped. Awesome tutorial btw.

Comment: Does someone knows how to do the same process in FreeBSD? I installed the binary editline but don't know how to execute or modify the program.

Answer (score 1):

I faced this issue in the ubuntu 18.04 version, installing the following packages worked for me

```
sudo apt install libeditline-dev 
sudo apt-get install libedit-dev
```

I refer to the following thread [Readline-Issue](https://github.com/orangeduck/BuildYourOwnLisp/issues/91)

Answer (score 0):

An answer from future.

I am also working on same tutorial. And I also get stuck at that point. Then removing `#include<editline/history.h>` solved my issue.

Thanks to that thread https://github.com/fabianishere/brainfuck/issues/57

P.S. I am using Archlinux

Answer (score 0):

to install editline header file use,

```
sudo apt-get install libedit-dev
```

or for fedora use,

```
su -c "yum install libedit-dev*"
```

then proceed to add the header files like this

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <editline/readline.h>
#include <editline/history.h>
```

use them as the Header files and then use the History and readline command as usual as given in the tutorial.

Then when compiling use (assuming your file name is "prompt.c" and the output compiled file is "PromptOutput"

```
gcc prompt.c -ledit -o PromptOutput
```

instead of

```
gcc prompt.c -o PromptOutput
```

this is because we haven't previously linked the program to "editline".

I am using Ubuntu 20.X.

for Arch, use

```
histedit.h
```

I hope that clears the query